# QSplashScreen.setPixmap moves Splashscreen back to default position

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5, qpixmap, qsplashscreen

I created a [QSplashScreen](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html) with a [QPixmap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) and moved it to the center of my second monitor (not the default monitor):

```
class SplashScreen(QSplashScreen):
  def __init__(self):
    self._pixmap = QPixmap("test1.png")
    super(SplashScreen, self).__init__(self._pixmap)

    screen = 1
    scr = qApp.desktop().screenGeometry(screen)
    self.move(scr.center() - self.rect().center()) # move to second screen
```

I'm now trying to add something to my pixmap, while SplashScreen is displayed:

```
  def drawSomething(self):
    add = QPixmap('test2.png')
    painter = QPainter(self._pixmap)
    painter.drawPixmap(0,0, add)
    #nothing happing so far
    self.repaint() # nothing happening
    self.setPixmap(self._pixmap) # changes shown, but moved back to default-screen
```

It seems like the QPixmap used to create the QSplashScreen got copied and isn't the same reference anymore, so changes on this have no direct effect.

Furthermore, using [`setPixmap()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html#setPixmap) moves the SplashScreen back on the default-monitor.

---

Is there an option to directly paint on the active QPixmap of the Splashscreen or to set a new one without being in need of moving the screen again?

<sub>(using the move-command doesn't seems like a good option, when you repaint quickly in a short period of time - the splashscreen then flashes on both monitors)</sub>

---

usage example:

```
app = QApplication([])
splash = SplashScreen()
splash.show()
splash.drawSomething()
exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had success with reimplementing the [`paintEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) with a `QPainter` on `self`:

```
def paintEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
    painter = QPainter(self)
    pixmap = QPixmap('test2.png')
    #self.setMask(pixmap.mask()) # optional for transparency painting
    painter.drawPixmap(0,0, pixmap)
```

---

However, reimplementing the [`drawContents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html#drawContents) funktion [like S.Monteleone suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49832113/4464653) worked fine too:

```
def drawContents(self, painter):
    painter.drawPixmap(0,0, QPixmap('test2.png'))
    super(SplashScreen, self).drawContents(painter)
```

Remember to also call super, after your painting, to not lose the drawing of [messages shown](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html#showMessage) on the QSplashScreen.

> *The default implementation draws the message passed by showMessage().*

Answer (score 1):

You should reimplmement the [drawContents](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsplashscreen.html#drawContents) function to perform painting on the QSplashScreen QPixmap.